# If I build a low pass gaussian filter in the frequency domain should I also normalize it with the sum of the filter coefficients?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I saw two examples of applying a Gaussian low pass filter to a MATLAB image: one when the filter was built in the spatial domain and was normalized with the sum of the filter coefficients, and another where the filter was built in the frequency domain and no normalization was made.

Is it consistent that no normalization is needed in the frequency domain and why is it different in this aspect from the spatial domain?

Comment: I tried to explain what the normalization is for in my answer. I will have to vote to close this question though, as questions which are not programming-related are off-topic for stackoverflow. You are much more likely to get good answers on the [Signal Processing StackExchange site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about filtering theory and not about implementation / programming issues.

Answer (score 2):

The normalization in the time (spatial) domain is done to ensure a unity gain at DC. For a simple length-3 FIR filter, such as

```
y(n) = h(0)*x(n) + h(1)*x(n-1) + h(2)*x(n-2)
```

you would divide the filter coefficients `h(0)`, `h(1)` and `h(2)` by their sum (`h(0)+h(1)+h(2)`), so if `x` is a constant signal, `y(n)` would equal to `x(n)` after some time, which is usually exactly what you want for a lowpass filter.

If you design a lowpass filter in the frequency range, you will define the frequency response - usually in the *z*-domain, e.g. a filter like:

```
H(z) = (1 + b*z^-1) / (1 - a*z^-1)
```

The DC-gain of such a filter is now simply `H(0)`, so by choosing `H(0) = 1`, you will get the same normalization as in the time-domain filter. In the example I've shown you, that would result in `H(0) = -b/a`. To achieve unity gain at DC, you would therefore have to set `-b/a = 1`.